# Can't posting blob in Document

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I got the Problem in the following code example:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=zpanel_module_autoinstaller_core', 'paneluser', 'asdasd');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select type, data from cms_pictures where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
?>
```

If I run this code, I got this Warning in my Apache error.log:

PHP Warning:  fpassthru() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /etc/..../test.php on line 10

So I think I got wrong Data in my Database, but it didn't looks like. If I take a look in PHPMyAdmin, I got a valid Picture. So I think, that I put all Data correctly into the Database. If I Click on the Blob in PHPMyAdmin I got a valid Image back.

Got anybody a idea? Can't find my failure.

Thanks a lot

Comment: please go through this link
http://us3.php.net/fpassthru

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/fpassthru. This function expects a filehandle, and you're trying to stuff in a string. You just need `echo $lob`.

Comment: Big sorry :( Now it is running fine. Thanks a lot.